# Not Able to Count Less/ Greater Than a Value in MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to COUNT rows less or greater than 100 in MYsQL table using PHPMyAdmin

```
SELECT HAVING COUNT(`roadLength`) > 100 AS stop3 FROM `single-ecolo-dis-yes-tbl`
```

and

```
SELECT HAVING COUNT(`roadLength`)< 100 FROM `single-ecolo-dis-yes-tbl`
```

but I am getting this error

```
SELECT HAVING COUNT(`roadLength`) > 100 FROM `single-ecolo-dis-yes-tbl`
 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING COUNT(`roadLength`) > 100 FROM `single-ecolo-dis-yes-tbl`
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

[image]

can you please let me know why this is happening? and how I can fix this?

Comment: Your attempt is so far removed from SQL syntax, that I would suggest that you learn a little bit about the language before attempting to use it.

Comment: Please don't use [code screenshot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors?cb=1): copy and paste text instead.

Comment: I concur with Gordon. Here is a good place to start, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html, it is the very first result when you search google for "mysql select".

Comment: Ok relax guys this is a question and ask website professors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`having` is to reduce the groups in a query and has no business in the `select` clause. It is a `clause` for itself

```
SELECT SUM(`roadLength` > 100) AS stop3 
FROM `single-ecolo-dis-yes-tbl`
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, for a simple count like this, you would put the condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as stop3
FROM `single-ecolo-dis-yes-tbl` t
WHERE t.roadLength > 100 ;
```

This allows the optimizer to use an index on `roadLength`, if one is available.